# Compare numeric values as string

Tags: c#, string

I have a method which gets two string. These strings can contain numbers, ASCII chars or both at the same time.

The algorithm works like this:

1. Split both strings into char Arrays A and B.
2. Try to parse element A<sub>i</sub> and B<sub>i</sub> to an int
3. Compare element A<sub>i</sub> with element B<sub>i</sub>, in case of integers use direct comparison, in case of chars use ordinal string comparison.
4. Do work based on the result

Now, I'm wondering: Do I really need to parse the elements to int? I simply could compare each element in an ordinal string comparison and would get the same result, right?
What are the performance implications here? Is parsing and normal comparison faster than ordinal string comparison? Is it slower?

Is my assumption (using ordinal string comparison instead of parsing and comparing) correct?

Here is the method in question:

```
internal static int CompareComponentString(this string componentString, string other)
{
    bool componentEmpty = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(componentString);
    bool otherEmtpy = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(other);

    if (componentEmpty && otherEmtpy)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (componentEmpty)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (otherEmtpy)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    string[] componentParts = componentString.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] otherParts = other.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(componentParts.Length, otherParts.Length); i++)
    {
        string componentChar = componentParts[i];
        string otherChar = otherParts[i];
        int componentNumVal, otherNumVal;
        bool componentIsNum = int.TryParse(componentChar, out componentNumVal);
        bool otherIsNum = int.TryParse(otherChar, out otherNumVal);

        if (componentIsNum && otherIsNum)
        {
            if (componentNumVal.CompareTo(otherNumVal) == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            return componentNumVal.CompareTo(otherNumVal);
        }
        else
        {
            if (componentIsNum)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (otherIsNum)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            int comp = string.Compare(componentChar, otherChar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (comp != 0)
            {
                return comp;
            }
        }
    }

    return componentParts.Length.CompareTo(otherParts.Length);
}
```

This are strings that might be used. I might add only the part **after** the minus sign is used.

- 1.0.0-alpha
- 1.0.0-alpha.1
- 1.0.0-alpha.beta
- 1.0.0-beta.2

Comment: It would be easier for us if you can give some examples of your strings.

Comment: If you're only comparing one digit at a time, a string comparison will give you the same result as parsing and performing an integer comparison.  But you should also consider if there are cases where digits might be compared with ASCII and if so, what should happen.

Comment: I added the code I'm currently using

Comment: Could your integers have more than one digit? Something like `11.12.13-alpha`? Are the dots separating signs? Is the minus a separating sign? Do you rather want an alphanumeric comparison of `0001.0001.0001-alpha`  (and - to come back to my example `0011.0012.0013-alpha`)?

Comment: The strings are the same as describe in the 2.0 Semantic version standard and there the prerelease and build parts. I updated my initial question again.

Comment: _"I simply could compare each element in an ordinal string comparison"_ unless you compare numbers of different character length like `2` and `10`

Comment: @grek40 What would be the difference?

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot In a string comparison, "10" is less than "2", because the first character is a "1". In integer comparison, 2 is less than 10

Comment: That's the reason why I suggested the padded format. Doing so alphanumeric and integer comparison is the same ...

Comment: Hi, I'm curious:Could you solve your problem?

Comment: @Shnugo: Yes I was able to solve it. However it was never about "not working", but more about: "What is efficient with less code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this method you can create a compare string for each of your string. These strings are comparable by simple alphanumeric comparison.

Assumptions:

- There is a minus in the string separating the common part and the indiv part
- **before** the minus is **always** a substring of three integer values divided by a dot
- These integer values are not higher than 999 (look at variable "MaxWidth1")
- **behind** the minus is another substring consisting of several parts, also divided by a dot
- The second substring's parts may be numeric or alphanumeric with a max. width of 7 (look at "MaxWidth2")
- The second substring consists of max. 5 parts (MaxIndivParts)

Put this method wherever you want:

```
public string VersionNumberCompareString(string versionNumber, int MaxWidth1=3, int MaxWidth2=7,int MaxIndivParts=5){
    string result = null;

    int posMinus = versionNumber.IndexOf('-');
    string part1 = versionNumber.Substring(0, posMinus);
    string part2 = versionNumber.Substring(posMinus+1);

    var integerValues=part1.Split('.');
    result = integerValues[0].PadLeft(MaxWidth1, '0');
    result += integerValues[1].PadLeft(MaxWidth1, '0');
    result += integerValues[2].PadLeft(MaxWidth1, '0');

    var alphaValues = part2.Split('.');
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxIndivParts;i++ ) {
        if (i <= alphaValues.GetUpperBound(0)) {
            var s = alphaValues[i];
            int casted;
            if (int.TryParse(s, out casted)) //if int: treat as number
                result += casted.ToString().PadLeft(MaxWidth2, '0');
            else //treat as string
                result += s.PadRight(MaxWidth2, ' ');
    }
    else
        result += new string(' ', MaxWidth2);
}
return result;    }
```

You call it like this:

```
var s1 = VersionNumberCompareString("1.3.0-alpha.1.12"); 
//"001003000alpha  00000010000012              "
var s2 = VersionNumberCompareString("0.11.4-beta");      
//"000011004beta                               "
var s3 = VersionNumberCompareString("2.10.11-beta.2");   
//"002010011beta   0000002                     "
```

Be aware of the final `"` sign. All strings are of the same length!

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

that's .net comparison logic for ascii strings -

```
  private unsafe static int CompareOrdinalIgnoreCaseHelper(String strA, String strB)
    {
        Contract.Requires(strA != null);
        Contract.Requires(strB != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        int length = Math.Min(strA.Length, strB.Length);

        fixed (char* ap = &strA.m_firstChar) fixed (char* bp = &strB.m_firstChar)
        {
            char* a = ap;
            char* b = bp;

            while (length != 0) 
            {
                int charA = *a;
                int charB = *b;

                Contract.Assert((charA | charB) <= 0x7F, "strings have to be ASCII");

                // uppercase both chars - notice that we need just one compare per char
                if ((uint)(charA - 'a') <= (uint)('z' - 'a')) charA -= 0x20;
                if ((uint)(charB - 'a') <= (uint)('z' - 'a')) charB -= 0x20;

                //Return the (case-insensitive) difference between them.
                if (charA != charB)
                    return charA - charB;

                // Next char
                a++; b++;
                length--;
            }

            return strA.Length - strB.Length;
        }
    }
```

having said that, Unless you have a strict performance constaint,  i would say if you get the same result from an already implemented & tested function, its better to reuse it and not to reinvent the wheel.
It saves so much time in implementation, unit testing, debugging & bug fixing time. & helps keep the software simple.